# Make imported function use new variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

im trying to write some unit tests to one of my older apps.
I didn't think back then that i would want to use functions outside of main file so i used a lot of local variables in them. My problem is that after importing them they are trying to use variables from other scope. Is there a way to make them use new scope without changing old file?

```
\\foo.js

let arr
exports.foo = function foo() {
  return arr[0]
}

\\foo.test.js

let arr = ['bar']
let foo = require('../test/supreme.spec.js').foo
console.log(foo())//undefined, want 'bar'
```

I get it that's probably a really bad practise, but thats an old code and i dont wan't to mess with it right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire). It was designed specifically for such cases:

```
let rewire = require('rewire')

let fooModule = rewire('../lib/foo.js')

fooModule.__set__('arr', [ 'bar' ])
console.log(fooModule.foo()) // bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible because of such thing as a closure and Lexical environment of the function. The function 'remembers' all the variables in the same scope as it was created in, so unless they are properties of that function they are not accessible form the outside. That's what makes encapsulation possible in Object-Oriented Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The scope is isolated from module to module, but you can add a parameter with a default value.

```
exports.foo = function foo(arr = ['test data 1', 'test data 2']) {
  return arr[0]
}
```

Then it can be called as `foo()`, but also as `foo(['other data'])`.